# Overly Regular PDE Solution - where's my mistake?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I was looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163149/boundedness-of-solutions-for-the-laplacian) and attempting to come up with my own answer when I "proved" a statement which seems far too strong: if $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$, then the unique solution to $u-\Delta u=f$ is in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. In particular, this would imply $H^2(\mathbb R^n)\subset L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. Could someone look at my working and see where my mistake is? (Or else verify that the statement is true, although I doubt this is the case.)

Using the convention that the Fourier transform is given by
$$\mathcal Fg(t)=\int g(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot t}\ \mathrm dx$$
for $g\in L^1(\mathbb R^n)\cap L^2(\mathbb R^n)$, one can easily show that the unique solution $u$ to $u-\Delta u=f$ is
$$u=\mathcal F^{-1}\left(\frac{\mathcal Ff(t)}{1+4\pi^2|t|^2}\right).$$
Let $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ be non-negative with $\int\varphi=1$ and define $\varphi_k(x)=k^{-n}\varphi(kx)$. Then $f_k:=f*\varphi_k\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$, so in particular $f_k\in\mathcal S$ where $\mathcal S$ is the space of Schwarz functions. Using the fact that $\mathcal F:\mathcal S\rightarrow\mathcal S$ is a bijection, $\mathcal Ff_k\in\mathcal S$ and hence
$$g_k:=\frac{\mathcal Ff_k(t)}{1+4\pi^2|t|^2}\in\mathcal S.$$
It follows that both $u_k:=\mathcal F^{-1}g_k$ and its Fourier transform are integrable, so by the Fourier inversion theorem $u_k(x)=\int g_k(t)e^{2\pi ix\cdot t}\ \mathrm dt$. Now since $\mathcal Ff_k=\mathcal F(f*\varphi_k)=(\mathcal Ff)(\mathcal F\varphi_k)$ and $\|\mathcal F\varphi_k\|_\infty\leq\|\varphi_k\|_1=1$, it follows that
$$\|u_k\|_\infty\le\int\frac{|\mathcal Ff(t)|}{1+4\pi^2|t|^2}\ \mathrm dt\le\|\mathcal Ff\|_2\left(\int\frac1{(1+4\pi^2|t|^2)^2}\ \mathrm dt\right)^{1/2}.$$
Since $(\varphi_k)$ is an approximate inentity of convolution, $f_k\to f$ in $L^2$. All the linear maps involved are $L^2$-bounded so $u_k\to u$ in $L^2$ and hence almost everywhere along a subsequence. Hence we conclude
$$\|u\|_\infty\le\|\mathcal Ff\|_2\left(\int\frac1{(1+4\pi^2|t|^2)^2}\ \mathrm dt\right)^{1/2}<\infty$$
and so $u\in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: $f_k$ is not necessarily compactly supported. Also, what makes you conclude that $$\int \frac{dt}{(1+4\pi^2|t|^2)^2}<\infty?$$ You're in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so for big enough $n$ there's issues at $\infty$. The idea is right, but it's not completely trivial (see my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163149/boundedness-of-solutions-for-the-laplacian/1164211#1164211) for a related question).

Comment: Ah, of course! For $n\ge4$ the integral does not converge, you are correct. Do you think it is possible to use a sequence of cut-off functions (so we have $f_k\in C^\infty_c$) to make my argument correct for $n<4$? Also I saw your answer in your other question - the fact that $G_2\in L^1$ was not obvious to me.

Comment: That is precisely the problem. This integral is finite iff $n \le 3$. It diverges logarithmically if $n = 4$. And $H^2(\mathbb{R^n}) \subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R^n})$ if $n \le 3$. For $n = 4$ this is no longer an embedding (but a logarithmic term is needed by Brezis-Gallouet-Wainger).

Comment: Well, you just answered your first question: Since $\| u\|_{H^2}=\| f\|_{L^2}$ we have that for $n\leq 3$ we get $\| u\|_{L^\infty} \leq \| f\|_{L^2}$. The fact that $G_2$ is in $L^1$ is not completely trivial since there are some issues at $0$ (it blows up as $|x|^{2-n}$ at $0$), this comes from the fact that the multiplier $(1+|\xi|^2)^{-1}$ lacks enough decay at $\infty$.